# Font size increase delay issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [this](https://codepen.io/v_trefil/pen/oxmdqw) loading screen animation I found on Codepen. On mobile devices I found the screen sizes to be really small. I am using media queries to increase the size like this

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
          .counter p, counter h1{
            font-size:200%
          }
       }
```

The font size only increases after the loading animation reaches 100%. I cannot figure out why

Comment: Add `.` to your `counter h1`

Comment: `min-width` means your media query will start with `576px`. I think it should be `max-width` since the  mobile resolutions are mostly considered from `320px`+

Comment: you need to use em or rem which will better solution for responsive device.. em and rpm calculate the value based on device structure..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
@media (max-width: 576px) { 
  .counter p, .counter h1{
    font-size:2em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the **2em** to whatever value you wish.